# Number of columns in a vim file

Tags: command-line, vim

Is there an equivalent for wc -l to have the number of columns of a vim file? (I have a file with several rows and columns separated by spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you have equal number of columns in all the rows, this should work for you:

```
awk -F' ' '{print NF; exit}' <filename>
```

`awk` is a patter scanning language

`-F` is the field separator; `' '` tells awk that columns are space separated. This will work even if there is more than one space between two columns.

`print NF; exit` prints the number of fields and exits

**Caveat:** This will report the number of columns in the first line only.

Refer to [awk manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) for more options.

---

**Source:** [Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629330/unix-count-of-columns-in-file)

Comment: space is default field-separator for `awk`. So you can use `awk '{print NF; exit}' <filename>` for the same.

Comment: Better to specify it explicitly so other users can modify it to their needs. Anyways, thanks @souravc!

Comment: This is absolutely fine. I just said it as OP asked in question "columns separated by spaces". never mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Just press `CTRL-W v` and the file you are working one will be split to two separate independent columns. Repeat `CTRL-W v` as many times as you want.

Set scrollbind: `set scrollbind` to columns that you want to scroll in-sync.

For example:

```
vim afile         # Open a file
^w v              # split it
gg                # go to top
:set scrollbind   # bind this one
^w l              # go to the new split
L                 # got to bottom of this split
zt                # make it the top line
:set scrollbind   # bind with this one
```

Now while you move on one columnt, the other one scrolls so as if the first column overflows the text to the second column.